# SQLite check for duplicate rows

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite database for an art exhibition. In the table "exhibits" I have columns for the artwork ID, the exhibition space ID, a begin date, and an end date. The default value for "end date" is NULL. 
Of course, the same artwork cannot be displayed in two different spaces at once. So I want to ensure that a new row with an artwork ID is not created unless all existing rows with that same artwork ID have a non-null end date.
Is there some kind of constraint, trigger, etc. that I can add to the table to ensure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on writing triggers for SQLite but something like this should work,

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_open_ended_exhibit BEFORE INSERT ON exhibits
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT, "Open ended exhibit exists") 
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM exhibits WHERE artworkID = NEW.artworkID AND enddate IS NULL);
END
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your information “Artwork” cannot be displayed twice in the same show which means the EndTime is a unique field when constraining it together with Artwork. So by making these two together your constrain you won’t be able to insert a record if you already have “artwork and NULL”.

So yeah you can just create a unique constrain on these two columns.

```
 CREATE TABLE testConstrain (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  endDate DATETIME
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX testConstrain
ON testConstrain(id, endDate);

INSERT INTO testConstrain VALUES('1',null)
INSERT INTO testConstrain VALUES('2','01-01-2018')
INSERT INTO testConstrain VALUES('1','01-01-2018')
INSERT INTO testConstrain VALUES('1',null)
```

`

And you will get:
    Started executing query at Line 11
(1 row affected)
(1 row affected)
(1 row affected) 
**Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
Cannot insert duplicate key** row in object 'bginsburg.testConstrain' with unique index 'testConstrain'. The duplicate key value is (1, ). 
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: No you cannot, two rows with NULL in the same column will not be considered equal.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson edited my comment so you can try it and see it DOES work.
Triggers are bad habit and shouldn't be used when you have such an easy and simple solution.

Comment: I tried to reproduce but failed, I can insert several rows with null values